# byobu in ubuntu always attaches to the same session

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

It used to be when I ran byobu I would get a new session with a new socket and I could open multiple windows in that one. Now when I run it it concurrently attaches to the same one existing byobu session such that when I type in one, the terminal updates in both.
How can I force it to start a new session?

Answer (score 2):

If `byobu` is using `screen` then typing `byobu bash` (or whatever shell you use instead of `bash`) should start a new session and not link to the previously running one.

Else if `byobu` is using `tmux` then `byobu new` or `byobu new-session` should do the same thing.

`byobu -v` should tell you what version of `byobu` and which of `tmux` or `screen` is being used.

I just asked the same question over on  Ask Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/a/94568/41467

Answer (score 0):

I found this was commented out in my .bashrc

alias screen='byobu -m $1 $2 $3 $4'

I put it back in and it started working again. This seems like a really poorly put together kludge, but at least it works.

Comment: FYI (unrelated to the problem): `$1`, `$2`, etc. *do not work* in aliases; all arguments are appended automatically, so `alias screen='byobu -m'`. Specifying separate arguments is only allowed in functions, e.g. `screen() { byobu -m "$@"; }`